# How do i show the leading zeros when exporting to excel?

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am creating an excel report by changing the content type.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
```

I have values that contain leading zeros. The issue is when exporting to excel the leading zeros are missing.

e.g.

000123 -> 123

I know that this can be changed manually via excel. The question is how can i accomplish this programmatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Export your `application/vnd.ms-excel` as an HTML table, it gives you access to a variety of worksheet formatting options:

Use:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
```

And send something like the following:

```
<table border="1">
<caption>This is a caption, it appears centered across all columns</caption>
<colgroup>
<col width="100">
<col width="200">
</colgroup>
<tr valign="bottom">
<td><b>Header 1</b></td>
<td filter="all"><b>Header 2 (filterable)</b></td>
</tr>
<tr valign="top">
<td style="vnd.ms-excel.numberformat:$#,##0.00_)[semicolon]($#,##0.00)">1</td>
<td style="vnd.ms-excel.numberformat:00000000">2</td>
</tr>
<tr valign="top">
<td style="vnd.ms-excel.numberformat:$#,##0_)[semicolon]($#,##0)">3</td>
<td style="vnd.ms-excel.numberformat:00000000">4</td>
</tr>
<tr valign="top">
<td style="vnd.ms-excel.numberformat:$#,##0.00_)[semicolon]($#,##0.00)">-5</td>
<td style="vnd.ms-excel.numberformat:00000000">2</td>
</tr>
<tr valign="top">
<td style="vnd.ms-excel.numberformat:$#,##0.00_)[semicolon][red]$#,##0.00">-7</td>
<td style="vnd.ms-excel.numberformat:00000000">8</td>
</tr>
<tr valign="bottom">
<td formula="=sum(a2:a5)" style="vnd.ms-excel.numberformat:$#,##0.00_)[semicolon][red]$#,##0.00"></td>
<td formula="=average(b2:b5)" style="vnd.ms-excel.numberformat:00000000"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Note that by using the HTML table syntax you can add a [column AutoFilter](http://archive.baarns.com/DevOnly/Notes/TechEd/Intr9713.asp), specify the vertical row alignment, control the width of columns, combine columns with `<colspan>` (not shown), add [formulas](http://archive.baarns.com/DevOnly/Notes/TechEd/Intr9711.asp) and specify the format of column data with [vnd.ms-excel.numberformat](http://archive.baarns.com/DevOnly/Notes/TechEd/Intr9712.asp). You can even do [Crosstab (PivotTables)](http://archive.baarns.com/DevOnly/Notes/TechEd/Intr9714.asp) (not shown).

I had a link to more comprehensive documentation about what HTML tags and attributes are supported, and what they do, but I seem to have misplaced it. If anyone else has a good link to Microsoft documentation about this, feel free to [edit my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1209326/edit) or include a comment.

EDIT: It seems that you can do [a lot more with HTML/XML](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/kaushikborah28/79Nick08302007171404PM/79Nick.aspx) to build complicated Excel worksheets. I've never gone to these lengths, but it is interesting to know what is possible.

Comment: Thanks for that. Although my answer servers my purpose this is definitely the correct way to do it.

Comment: What do you use as the file extension - XLS, HTM, CSV or something else?

Answer (score 8):

Ive found the answer, you can surround the value in quotes and prefix it with an equals sign to preserve the leading zeros.

="000123"

See here: [Excel vs. Leading Zero & Space](http://www.creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm#CSVAndExcel)

Answer (score 0):

Export the column with a leading `'` (apostrophe).

Comment: This is not the best solution as the column then contains the apostrophe.