# exporting to excel removes leading zeros. css styles to the table does not carry over to the excel export

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

I have an asp:table which I want to exported to excel. One of my fields are alpha numeric and when exported to excel the leading 0s are stripped off.

After going through this thread: [Validation (CSS 2.0): 'mso-number-format' is not a known CSS property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148003/validation-css-2-0-mso-number-format-is-not-a-known-css-property-name)

I would like to use the css method "mso-number-format:\@;.But the css is not exported to excel.

I just tried to test it with simpler css things like bold font etc but its not getting carried over. I can see that if I surround my asp:Label with  tags this change gets carried over to the excel but not the css bold .

Other solutions in other thread does not work for me as ="00111" shows up as desired in excel but in the web form it shows up as ="00111" which is not what i want.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208860/how-do-i-show-the-leading-zeros-when-exporting-to-excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the inputs but that did not work for me. I just worked around it with a trick. In the requirement I had, I had to show SomeAccountNumber:000000111112222

So I worked around it by putting "SomeAccountNumber" in one label and ":" + "000000111112222
" in the other label.

I know its not the correct way to fix the problem but just worked for my case. 
Might help others to in similar scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see your export code to give an accurate answer, but you might want to try a String.Format({0:0#}, fieldStringData) when you are doing the export.  This will ensure passing the string to excel will include the leading zero.